# Set language for site name

Tags: translation

You can programmatically set the language of Joomla with the following code:

```
$lang = JFactory::getLanguage();
$bla = $lang->setLanguage('fr-FR');
$lang->load();
```

But when you try to get sitename, it's not translated:

```
$app = JFactory::getApplication('site');
$sitename = $app->get('sitename');  // <--- Still in English
```

Did I miss something? Does `load()` need an argument to load the translation of sitemap?

**Edit:** One solution, using raw database query to get it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19511362/get-joomla-sitename-in-different-language

Comment: It's not translated because your only geting the site name from the global configuration

Comment: Not true, the site name is stored in the __languages table, too.

Answer (score 1):

(Tested in Joomla 3.7.x)

In the Joomla backend:

**Extensions -> Languages -> Content -> edit your installed languages -> tab "sitename".**